# Django Haystack + Elasticsearch - how to return results with a small edit distance from query?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

So we are using Django-haystack with the Elasticsearch backend to index a bunch of data for searching. It is very fast and is working great for the most part, but I notice something that I want that seems to be absent. For example, consider the search query `"cellar door"`. I would want a query that is slightly off, like a misspelling, e.g. `"cellar dor"` or `"celar door"` to match results for `"cellar door"`. If I try queries like this with our current setup it returns 0 results. I tried using an EdgeNgramField in the search index on the field we wanted to index, but this seems to have absolutely no effect.

Thanks.

Comment: you should use Fuzzy query, find example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000714/how-can-i-do-a-fuzzy-search-using-django-haystack-and-the-elasticsearch-backend

Answer (score -1):

Use suggest to perform spell check.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/index/_search?search_type=count' -d '{

{
   "suggest": {
      "body": {
         "text": "celar door",
         "term": {
            "field": "summary",
            "analyzer": "simple"
         }
      }
   }
}'
```